# Exporting to fbx - halo material is lost

Tags: materials, export

I have a simple cube (the starting scene cube) that I applied a halo material to. When I export to fbx and use the fbx in xna, it just shows the normal grey cube, sans halo. How would I keep the material when exporting?

Comment: Is there some sort of halo material in XNA? It's necessary that the software you're exporting to has some sort of halo material. Even so, Blender may not even export halo materials. I would recommend using the exports for nothing more than the meshes (and UV Maps). Create all the materials later on in the game engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that Blender's .FBX exporter exports halo's. Even if it did, the software you're exporting to (in this case XNA) also has to have support for halo materials.

Most of the time, it's just best to export meshes, UV maps and animations with the exporters, as materials and lights vary wildly from program to program. Do all the material setup in the target program.